# Spark QueueStream never exhausted

Tags: apache-spark, dstream

Puzzled on a piece of code I borrowed from the internet for research purposes. This is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import scala.collection.mutable

val spark = ... 

val sc = spark.sparkContext
val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(1)) 

val rddQueue = new mutable.Queue[RDD[Char]]()
val QS = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue) 

QS.foreachRDD(q=> {
   print("Hello") // Queue never exhausted
   if(!q.isEmpty) {
       ... do something
       ... do something
   }
}
)

//ssc.checkpoint("/chkpoint/dir") if unchecked causes Serialization error

ssc.start()
for (c <- 'a' to 'c') {
    rddQueue += ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(List(c))
}
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I was tracing through it just to check and noted that "hello" is being printed out forever:

```
 HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello and so on
```

I would have thought the queueStream would exhaust after 3 iterations.

So, what have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It is actually exhausted, but the looping continues and that's why the statement

```
 if(!q.isEmpty)
```

is there.

OK, would have thought it would just stop, or, rather not execute, but not so. I remember now. An empty RDD will result, if nothing streamed, based on timing of batch interval. Leaving for others as there was an upvote.

> However, even though legacy, it is a bad example as adding checkpoint
>   causes a Serialization error. Leaving it for the benefit of others.
>
> ```
> ssc.checkpoint("/chkpoint/dir")
> ```